# Passing variables into Openquery and SQL Injection

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection, openquery

I have two databases (A and B), both SQL Server, on different servers. These databases are connected with a linked server.

I have to be able to insert rows with distinct values into a table in database B using a stored procedure on database A. This stored procedure uses `OPENQUERY` in order to do the `INSERT` statements into database B.

I know `OPENQUERY` does [not accept variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) for its arguments. `OPENQUERY` has [specific syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on how to do an insert into a linked DB:

```
INSERT OPENQUERY (OracleSvr, 'SELECT name FROM joe.titles')  
VALUES ('NewTitle');
```

Nevertheless, the MS [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query) shows a way to pass variables into a linked server query like this:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)

SELECT @VAR = 'CA'
SELECT @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'

EXEC (@TSQL)
```

And here is the issue. Lets say the table in database B has two columns, `ID` (`int`) and `VALUE` (`nvarchar(max)`)

Thus, for a stored procedure to be able to insert different values into a table in database B, my procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE openquery_insert
    @var1 int,
    @var2 nvarchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL_string nvarchar(max)
    SET @SQL_string = 'insert openquery(LINKEDSERVER, ''SELECT ID, VALUE from TABLE'') VALUES ('
    + CAST(@var1 AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ', ' 
    + '''' + CAST(@var2 AS NVARCHAR(max)) + ''''
    + ')'
        
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_string
END
END
```

The procedure can be called as

```
EXEC openquery_insert @var1 = 1, @var2 = 'asdf'
```

But if `@var2` were to be `' DROP TABLE B--`, a SQL injection attack would be successful.

Is there a way in order to prevent SQL Injection with `OPENQUERY`?

- I do not control what the values are for the arguments `@var1` and `@var2` when the procedure gets called
- I am not able to create functions or stored procedures on database B
- I have to use OPENQUERY, I can not use [four part naming](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1095/sql-server-four-part-naming/) in order to do the insert
- I have to use a stored procedure on DB A

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note on this - please remember that the maximum length for a string literal in `OPENQUERY` is 8K characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "hacky" way is to insert your arguments into a local table first and then do the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` using `OPENQUERY`.

This is all straightforward if your SP is ever called by one process in a synchronous fashion: you can have one table where you insert values into then execute `OPENQUERY` to grab them and then you delete those values from the table.

If concurrency is a requirement then you have to write logic that creates uniquely named tables etc. which quickly becomes somewhat messy.